# Getting Null Pointer Exception when using isEmpty() method

Tags: java, authentication, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement a login feature for my program but it's returning a null pointer exception.  I understand that this happens when you refer to a place in memory that has nothing in it, but as far as I can see I have instantiated all my objects properly - please correct me if I am wrong!

I am trying to implement an add user feature:  I have a list of usernames and passwords and I have an existing method which reads that file in and stores it in an array.  I want to write a new login to the list so I wrote a new method which converts this array to an ArrayList and will eventually write a new login to it and then write the Login file out again.  The problem is I am getting the Null Pointer Exception.

Method 1:

```
public String[] readFile(){
    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String Line;
    try {
        String line = br.readLine();
        do {                
            dataList.add(Line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        while (!line.isEmpty());
        br.close ();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String[] dataArr = new String[dataList.size()];
    dataArr = dataList.toArray(dataArr);

    return dataArr; // Returns an array containing the separate lines of the file
}
```

Method 2:

```
public void addNewUser (String username, String password){
    String[] dataArr = readFile();  // Read in the list of profiles and store it in an array
    ArrayList<String> dataAL = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(dataArr));   // store array of profiles as ArrayList
    dataAL.add(username + "\t" + password);

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are probably getting null pointer here

```
while (!line.isEmpty());
```

change it to

```
while(line!=null && !line.isEmpty())
```

If you paid attention to the exception's stack trace you should see the exact line where the exception is being raised

Comment: Just to explain to @user1058210, this will solve the problem because if the left side of the expression `(bool && bool2)` is false the right side will not be evaluated. So if `line` is `null` then `!line.isEmpty()` won't be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Pangea! And thanks for the explanation user1031312!

Comment: @user1058210 accept this as the answer if it is indeed the answer to ur question

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader.readLine() will return a null if the end of the stream is reached. So you want

```
while (line != null && !line.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the body of your `try` block to:

```
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {                
    dataList.add(Line);
    line = br.readLine();
}
br.close ();
```

If you want to ignore blank lines, change it to this:

```
String line = br.readLine();
while (line != null) {                
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
        dataList.add(Line);
    }
    line = br.readLine();
}
br.close ();
```

The other answers offered so far will stop the reading at the first blank line. (If you don't have blank lines, then you don't ever need to call `isEmpty()`.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are adding null values to the dataList in readFile method. Anyways, I've refactored your code:

**Method 1**:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile(){
    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        //File & File Reader/Stream Initialization Logic

        while(line = br.readLine() != null && !line.isEmpty()) {               
            dataList.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException IOE) {
        //IO Exception Handling
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //General Exception Handling
    } finally {
        //close the reader/streams here
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

**Method 2**:

```
public void addNewUser (String username, String password){
    ArrayList<String> dataAL = readFile();
    dataAL.add(username + "\t" + password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`package -> org.springframework.util

!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(line)

Internal Implementation:
public static boolean isEmpty(@Nullable Collection<?> collection) {
return (collection == null || collection.isEmpty());
}`